# Swagger-Codegen issue generating javascript or nodejs sdk

Tags: node.js, sdk, client, swagger-codegen

I am trying to generate client sdk which can be consumed with javascript on Browser or Nodejs on server side. 
I came across https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen which can create client sdk from swagger json.
So I am trying to create sdk for petsotre example, here is the command I use

```
swagger-codegen generate -i http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json -l javascript -o ./petstore
```

But I get error saying

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javascript

If I try nodejs-server as language it works fine but that generates server and not the client sdk I wanted.

How can I generate simple JS sdk which can be consumed both on browser and in nodejs app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`swagger-codegen` refers to Swagger Codegen v3 for OpenAPI 3.0 definitions. To generate code for OpenAPI 2.0 definitions, use `swagger-codegen@2` instead:

```
brew install swagger-codegen@2

swagger-codegen@2 generate -i http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json -l javascript -o ./petstore
```